# Definition of variable V occurring free in lambda expression E

Tags: lambda-calculus

What does the following mean?

$$
(\lambda V_1 V_2.E) E_1 E_2
$$

> "$V_2$ occurs free in $E_1$."

Does this mean $E_1$ contains references to $V_2$?

Could you explain with examples? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @PlanckWalk from libera #math.

Let's consider

$$
(\lambda v_1. \lambda v_2. \underline{sum})(\lambda w. v_2+1)(\underline{3})
$$

Here, $v_2$ occurs free in $(\lambda w. v_2 +1)$.

That's what it means.

Relatedly, substitution $E[E'/V]$ is invalid if any free variable in $E'$ gets bound in $E[E'/V]$.

For example,

$$
(\lambda w. \lambda v. \underline{sum} \ w)(\lambda w.v)
= (\lambda v. \underline{sum} \ w)[(\lambda w. v)/w]
= (\lambda v. \underline{sum} \ \lambda w. v)
$$

is invalid because free variable $v$ in $(\lambda w. v)$ gets bound in $\underline{sum}$.

Even simpler

$$
(\lambda v. \lambda w. v)(w)
= (\lambda w. v)[w/v]
= (\lambda w. w)
$$

is also invalid since free $w$ gets bound in $(\lambda w.w)$.